# Plotting with the x,y axis having smaller intervals

Tags: matlab, plot

I want to plot two functions and have the X and Y axis having smaller intervals than what is being shown.

Here is the plot

[image]

and here is my code

```
x = linspace(-2,2,100);    

plot (x, atan(x)), grid on;

ax = gca;
ax.XAxisLocation = 'origin';
ax.YAxisLocation = 'origin';

hold on 
plot(x, x-atan(x).*(1+x.^2))
hold off
```

The *x*-axis has intervals of 0.5, but the *y*-axis does not. Could someone please show me how to make the axis's have smaller intervals? I want to 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, and 0.4 between the 0 and 0.5 on the *x*-axis. Then do the same thing on the $y$-axis.

I'm looking through https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/getting-started-with-matlab.html right now, but haven't found how to do what I described above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to change the tick positions. This can be done in a few ways but programmatically:

`ax.XTick = -1.5:0.1:1.5`

This will change the values marked on the X-axis to be 0.1,0.2 etc. If you want to only use the smaller spacing on a particular part of the axis then you can set the tick values individually (eg `[-1 -0.5 0 0.1 0.2 0.3]`)

Changing the Y-axis is identical but with `YTick`

The documentation for this is [here](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_plots/change-tick-marks-and-tick-labels-of-graph-1.html)

Comment: How would I ignore the first 0.1 iteration mark? I mean, to just not show the first 0.1

Comment: If 0.1 is not in the vector you set XTick to, then it won't be a tick mark. So just construct the vector without 0.1 in it.